Why are Generate (G) and Propagate (P) Signals Calculated Bit-by-Bit in a Carry Look-Ahead Adder?
In carry look ahead adder, for G and P, why is it done bit by bit and not together like G = A . B fully??
For example if A = 1010 and B = 1101, we get G0=0,G1=0,G2=0,G3=1 and even if we do it like G=1000 right, so in the end each individual bits value is going to be the same??
(Note: I implemented it in a software(xilinx vivado using verilog), it doesn't work if I AND it as a whole, it only works when I do it bit by bit.)
